# Spring MVC: Unable to render View - ${} is rendering in view

Tags: java, spring-mvc, view

I am new to Spring MVC. My final View not rendering proper value, but rendering ${}

Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMvcFormExample</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.*" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">

            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

RegistrationController.jsp

```
package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(Model model) {
        User user = new User();     
        user.setUsername("xyz");
        model.addAttribute("user",user);

        System.out.println("up model "+ model.asMap().toString());

        return "Registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(Model model,@ModelAttribute User user) {
        System.out.println("user : "+ user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute(user);

        // implement your own registration logic here...


        System.out.println("model"  +model.asMap().toString());

        return "RegistrationSuccess";
    }
}
```

Registration.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
    <h1>reached here</h1>
        <form:form action="register" method="POST" commandName="user">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Spring MVC Form Demo - Registration</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy):</td>
                    <td><form:input path="birthDate" /></td>
                </tr>
<!--                <tr> -->
<!--                    <td>Profession:</td> -->
<%--                    <td><form:select path="profession" items="${professionList}" /></td> --%>
<!--                </tr> -->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
<h1>reached here</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

RegistrationSucess.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Registration Success</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">

        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Registration Succeeded!</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <h3>Thank you for registering! Here's the review of your details:</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td>${user.username}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail:</td>
                <td>${email}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Birthday:</td>
                <td>${user.birthDate}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Profession:</td>
                <td>${user.profession}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now At last The RegistrationSucess page is showing this :(
Please help me where I m doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image: RegistrationSucess.jsp Snap]

Comment: Try fixing your web.xml declaration (you're mixing 2.5 and 3.0 versions). Take this as example: http://javahowto.blogspot.fr/2010/07/sample-webxml-servlet-30-with-ejb-ref.html. Also, where do you deploy the app?

Comment: HI JB I changed the web.xml to below , but no luck , still getting the same output:(

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the EL evaluation is being getting disabled in your setting (I'm guessing version mismatch of servlet container and the web.xml declaration). Try adding the `isELIgnored` attribute by setting it to false and check

```
<%@ page  isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code copied from a sample project(Working). Just have removed few other bean definitions.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.classifieds" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.classifieds.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.classifieds.service" />

<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/,classpath:/META-INF/"
    mapping="/resources/**" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```